# How to send a class variable in byte[] type to web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I want to convert my class instance variable to byte[] , and then pass it to web service.
In my web service I try to convert it back to class -
 server gets this error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Unable to find assembly 'App_Web_xrrt4fej, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'

```
// client code:        
[Serializable]        
public class result        
{
          public string message { get; set; }
}    

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)    
{                   
      byte[] b = ObjectToByteArray(new result() {  message = "ok" });            
      string ss = serv.HelloWorld34(b);    
}

// server code:    
[Serializable]    
public class result    
{            
     public string message { get; set; }    
}

[WebMethod]    
public string HelloWorld34(byte[] arrBytes)    
{    
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();    
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();    
        memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);    
        memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);


        // the line that has error    
        result obj = (result)binForm.Deserialize(memStream);    
        return "1";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the result class in both the server and client project, create a separate class library project and declare the result class in it. Then reference the class library project in both your client and server code.